# HTML Text NOT Wrapping properly, horizontal scrollbar issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Building a simple text-based HTML document with limited CSS, and a single Jquery fueled button. I have 1 major issue: My text doesn't want to wrap, it just goes off the screen. It seems like something is wrong with any right-padding I try to apply. Help.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nightcorey/pen/xxwyNgR

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.daytext {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nighttext {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}

.holder div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    /*init z-index*/
}

.holder div.current {
    z-index: 1;
}

/*only this DIV will be visible*/
.one {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.two {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.wrap{
    margin:0 5% 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>corey</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="button">yay</button>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="one current">
            <div class="wrap">
            <p>Hi, I'm <a class="daytext" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/coreyhclay">Corey Clay</a>, a designer
                currently
                residing in Charlotte, North Carolina.
                <p>During the day, I attend <a class="daytext" href="https://www.uncc.edu">college</a>, work an
                    <a class="daytext"
                        href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g49232-d10404800-Reviews-Out_of_Time_Escape-Huntersville_North_Carolina.html?m=19905">
                        escape room</a>, and design <a class="daytext" href="https://webflow.com/coreyhclay">mockup
                        websites</a>.
                    My goal is to create a unique portfolio of development projects, and find work at a company that can
                    help me grow.</p>
                <p>I'm acquainted with tools such as Figma, Adobe Creative Suite, Visual Studio Code, Github, HTML5,
                    CSS, and
                    Javascript; I'm also learning SASS, React, and Jquery.</p>
                <p>Peek my <a class="daytext" href="url">resume</a>, check my <a class="daytext"
                        href="url">portfolio</a>,
                    and say <a class="daytext" href="url">hello</a>.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="wrap">
            <p>Hi, I'm <a class="nighttext" href="https://twitter.com/nightcorey">Corey Clay</a>, a musician currently residing in Charlotte, North Carolina.</p>

            <p>During the night, I produce <a class="nighttext" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVBCnAqJrUg">
            pop music</a>, DJ <a class="nighttext" href="https://soundcloud.com/nightcorey/nightcoreys-set-for-deskpop">live mixes</a>,
            and host a <a class="nighttext" href="https://soundcloud.com/nightcorey/nightcoreys-set-for-deskpop"> podcast
            about k-pop</a>. My goal is to collaborate with vocalists and performers to make sincere pop songs that damage speakers.</p>

            <p>I compose with tools like Ableton, Spire, Ozone, and a midi keyboard; I'm also learning chord theory, Serum, and general mixing techniques.</p>

            <p>Experience my <a class="nighttext" href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">website</a>, check my <a class="nighttext"
            href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">soundcloud</a>, and say <a class="nighttext" href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">hello</a>.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $("button").click(function () {
            if ($(".holder >div:last-child").hasClass("current")) {
                $(".holder >div:last-child").removeClass("current");
                $(".holder >div:first-child").addClass("current");
            } else {
                $(".current").removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your wrapper

```
.wrap {
    padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Removed some excess code, rewrited it a bit

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.daytext {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nighttext {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}

.holder > div {
    width: 100%;
   /* height: 100%;*/
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    /*init z-index*/
    display: none;
}

.holder > div.current {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

/*only this DIV will be visible*/
.one {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.two {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.wrap{
    padding:0 5% 0 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>corey</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="button">yay</button>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="one current">
            <div class="wrap">
            <p>Hi, I'm <a class="daytext" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/coreyhclay">Corey Clay</a>, a designer
                currently
                residing in Charlotte, North Carolina.
                <p>During the day, I attend <a class="daytext" href="https://www.uncc.edu">college</a>, work an
                    <a class="daytext"
                        href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g49232-d10404800-Reviews-Out_of_Time_Escape-Huntersville_North_Carolina.html?m=19905">
                        escape room</a>, and design <a class="daytext" href="https://webflow.com/coreyhclay">mockup
                        websites</a>.
                    My goal is to create a unique portfolio of development projects, and find work at a company that can
                    help me grow.</p>
                <p>I'm acquainted with tools such as Figma, Adobe Creative Suite, Visual Studio Code, Github, HTML5,
                    CSS, and
                    Javascript; I'm also learning SASS, React, and Jquery.</p>
                <p>Peek my <a class="daytext" href="url">resume</a>, check my <a class="daytext"
                        href="url">portfolio</a>,
                    and say <a class="daytext" href="url">hello</a>.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="wrap">
            <p>Hi, I'm <a class="nighttext" href="https://twitter.com/nightcorey">Corey Clay</a>, a musician currently residing in Charlotte, North Carolina.</p>

            <p>During the night, I produce <a class="nighttext" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVBCnAqJrUg">
            pop music</a>, DJ <a class="nighttext" href="https://soundcloud.com/nightcorey/nightcoreys-set-for-deskpop">live mixes</a>,
            and host a <a class="nighttext" href="https://soundcloud.com/nightcorey/nightcoreys-set-for-deskpop"> podcast
            about k-pop</a>. My goal is to collaborate with vocalists and performers to make sincere pop songs that damage speakers.</p>

            <p>I compose with tools like Ableton, Spire, Ozone, and a midi keyboard; I'm also learning chord theory, Serum, and general mixing techniques.</p>

            <p>Experience my <a class="nighttext" href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">website</a>, check my <a class="nighttext"
            href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">soundcloud</a>, and say <a class="nighttext" href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">hello</a>.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $("button").click(function () {
            if ($(".holder >div:last-child").hasClass("current")) {
                $(".holder >div:last-child").removeClass("current");
                $(".holder >div:first-child").addClass("current");
            } else {
                $(".current").removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is almost it! It gets rid of that pesky horizontal scrolling, and the word wrap looks great, but I need the button to work again. Right now it does nothing, and the text is just vertical scrolling, whereas I have the button fully working in my original example.

Comment: A few minutes. i will fix it

Comment: Updated an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of `overflow: hidden;` in the body.  Also I noticed you're button for "yay" is probably not doing what you'd like it to do.  You need to change the position from absolute to fixed.

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   
}

.daytext {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nighttext {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}

.holder div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    /*init z-index*/
}

.holder div.current {
    z-index: 1;
}

/*only this DIV will be visible*/
.one {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.two {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.wrap{
    margin:0 5% 0 5%;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>corey</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="button">yay</button>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="one current">
            <div class="wrap">
            <p>Hi, I'm <a class="daytext" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/coreyhclay">Corey Clay</a>, a designer
                currently
                residing in Charlotte, North Carolina.
                <p>During the day, I attend <a class="daytext" href="https://www.uncc.edu">college</a>, work an
                    <a class="daytext"
                        href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g49232-d10404800-Reviews-Out_of_Time_Escape-Huntersville_North_Carolina.html?m=19905">
                        escape room</a>, and design <a class="daytext" href="https://webflow.com/coreyhclay">mockup
                        websites</a>.
                    My goal is to create a unique portfolio of development projects, and find work at a company that can
                    help me grow.</p>
                <p>I'm acquainted with tools such as Figma, Adobe Creative Suite, Visual Studio Code, Github, HTML5,
                    CSS, and
                    Javascript; I'm also learning SASS, React, and Jquery.</p>
                <p>Peek my <a class="daytext" href="url">resume</a>, check my <a class="daytext"
                        href="url">portfolio</a>,
                    and say <a class="daytext" href="url">hello</a>.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div class="wrap">
            <p>Hi, I'm <a class="nighttext" href="https://twitter.com/nightcorey">Corey Clay</a>, a musician currently residing in Charlotte, North Carolina.</p>

            <p>During the night, I produce <a class="nighttext" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVBCnAqJrUg">
            pop music</a>, DJ <a class="nighttext" href="https://soundcloud.com/nightcorey/nightcoreys-set-for-deskpop">live mixes</a>,
            and host a <a class="nighttext" href="https://soundcloud.com/nightcorey/nightcoreys-set-for-deskpop"> podcast
            about k-pop</a>. My goal is to collaborate with vocalists and performers to make sincere pop songs that damage speakers.</p>

            <p>I compose with tools like Ableton, Spire, Ozone, and a midi keyboard; I'm also learning chord theory, Serum, and general mixing techniques.</p>

            <p>Experience my <a class="nighttext" href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">website</a>, check my <a class="nighttext"
            href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">soundcloud</a>, and say <a class="nighttext" href="NONSTOPPOP.jpg">hello</a>.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $("button").click(function () {
            if ($(".holder >div:last-child").hasClass("current")) {
                $(".holder >div:last-child").removeClass("current");
                $(".holder >div:first-child").addClass("current");
            } else {
                $(".current").removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's the jsfiddle also. https://jsfiddle.net/5h2aqr6t/

Comment: in body change width: 100vw; into width: 100%; to defeat the horizontal scroll